# Какой из двух запросов к базе данных работает быстрее?

Tags: php, mysql

Очень хитроопый вопрос для сабакосьедов в PHP, SQL. В общем, есть вот примерно такой огромный запрос к базе

```
  select
      book.*, lol as l, puk as p, boom as b,
      group_concat( separator '|') as id,
      ..........................
  from xxx as px
  left join ...............
  left join .................
  right join ................
  left join ...................
  where book>8000
  group by x.id
```

Выводит примерно 50 000 результатов в виде массивов. Есть php код, который
потом должен обработать результат. Обработка происходит в цикле с помощью php

```
for() {
if($dsf[$i]=='лол'){
    //печатаем
}
elseif($dfs[$i]=='ололо') {
    //печатаем
}
else {
    continue;
}
}
```

Вот как я переписал все вышеописанное

```
select * from (
      select
          book.*, lol as l, puk as p, boom as b,
          group_concat( separator '|') as id,
          ..........................
      from xxx as px
      left join ...............
      left join .................
      right join ................
      left join ...................
      where book>8000
      group by x.id
) as zzz where xz = 'лол' or xz='ололо';

for() {

if($dsf[$i]=='лол'){
    //печатаем
}

if($dfs[$i]=='ололо') {
    //печатаем
}

}
```

Обращаю ваше внимание, что во втором варианте проверка условий происходит в SQL, а потом тоже самое в ПХП. В отличие от первого варианта во втором обрабатывается меньше результатов и не используется continue.

**Вопрос:**

А что собственно быстрее работает? И какой вариант правильней?

Comment: как бы вы делали, все обрабатывали в базе или в пхп?

По мне так ответ очевиден, зачем грузить память когда все можно быстрее обработать в базе

а как думаете вы?

Comment: у вас в обоих случаях в цикле одинаковые конструкций. 
не вижу разницы, хотя во втором запросе вы поменяли как то фильтр.

Comment: не видеть разницы значит знать php sql на уровне самоучителя php за 12 дней или не знать вообще

Comment: Я предпочитаю на уровне бд сервака решать проблему. У вас во втором варианте так сделано. БД должен отвечать за данные, пэ-хэ-пэ за функционал, и .т.д. Каждому свое место.

Comment: в первом случае в выборке больше строк, зачем фильтровать еще в php совсем непонятно. также непонятен смысл топика. риторический вопрос и самоответ.

Comment: подумал вдруг найдется кто то кто скажет мне что я не прав и объяснит почему

вот напимер если я поменяю последнюю строчку вторго варианта на такую

as zzz where xz LIKE '%лол%' or xz LIKE '%ололо%';

появляется сомнение в том что вариант 2 будет работать быстрее первого из за LIKE

Comment: если xz индексируемое, тогда быстрее будет работать.

Comment: А зачем делать внешний селект?

Неужели нельзя в первом варианте условие добавить?

Comment: Попробуйте засечь время выполнения своих скриптов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Использовать right join не желательно. В результатирующем запросе он все равно приводится к left, потому лучше сразу так и писать.
2. Не используйте select book.* - лучше переписать все необходимые вам поля, это не так уж и трудно сделать один раз, а выгода всегда есть.
3. Естественно обрезка на уровне базы лучше - меньше данных передавать, а это и есть самое тонкое место.
4. Что мешает сделать фильтрацию прямо в самом запросе? where book>8000 AND( xz = 'лол' or xz='ололо') group by x.id; такой вариант будет быстрее всего.
5. посмотрите explain extended

Answer (score 0):

А че тут гадать то? Надо запустить на серваке что-то навроде [explain query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) и сервак сам ответит что быстрее.

Все зависит от наличия индексов, расположения таблиц и проч. мутоты.